# Why is it not allowed to assign const char * to const variable?

Tags: c++, char, constants

```
char* name;
const char* _name = "something";
name = _name; // conversion from const char * is not allowed
```

I know it is deprecated in c++, but I want to know why...

Why C++ banned `name` to point some literals `_name` points to?

Comment: afaik `name = _name` was never ok, but `char * _name = "something";` has been deprecated, because it is lying about constness

Comment: They are different types. If you have a `char*`, you are allowed to modify what it's pointing at. If `name = _name;` would be allowed, so would `name[0] = 'A';` which would modify the `const` array.

Comment: C originally allowed `char * _name = "something";`, because `const` hadn't been invented yet

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, and it still does allow it if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please explain why you believe that allowing it would improve anything for anyone.

Comment: It is not allowed because Cpp is type safe and C is a stupid language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `name` is non-const, it implies you are allowed to change the values.

For example:

```
*name = 'S'; // Change from "something" to "Something"
```

But `_name` was declared `const`, meaning you *cannot* change it.

You cannot take fixed, constant data, and assign it to a different variable; that is saying "It's OK if you change this".

Comment: Technically, `_name` wasn't declared const and you can change it. What you cannot change is the array that `_name` points to.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
name = _name; // conversion from const char * is not allowed
```

Was never allowed, because, sloppy speaking, it would turn something that is `const` into something that can be modified. `_name` is a pointer to `const char`, but `name` is a pointer to non-const `char`.

What was allowed in the past is

```
char* _name = "something";
```

It was always deprecated in C++, compilers typically issued a warning for it. It has been removed in C++11 (see [cppreference/string_literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)), because it is lying about constness. Even though `_name` is declared as `char*` you cannot modify the string pointed to by it. The reason it was allowed was compatibility to C which initially did not have `const`. It has been made an error, because trying to modify the string via `_name` always was wrong. The type of `"something"` is indeed `const char[10]`.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it is deprecated in c++

It's not "deprecated" (and never has been). It's simply not allowed. The program is ill-formed. See 463035818_is_not_a_number's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69044182/2079303) for something that used to be deprecated and is a bit similar.

> Why is it not allowed

Pointers to const aren't implicitly convertible to pointers to non-const because of "const safety" (or "const correctness") which is a sub-concept of "type safety". In very short and abstract description: The type system of the language tries to prevent the programmer from making obvious mistakes.

If an object is const, then it cannot be modified. Attempting to modify a const object results in undefined behaviour (UB). UB is very, very bad. You must never modify a const object.

A pointer to const may point to a const object such as it does in the example. Since it isn't possible to modify the pointed object directly through it, this is fine. You can however modify objects directly through pointers to non-const. Thus, pointing to a const object with a pointer to non-const is unsafe. Since a pointer to const may point to a const object, converting a pointer to const into a pointer to non-const is unsafe. Hence, it is good that such conversion isn't implicit.

Answer (score 2):

What would the point of using `const` be if it's to easy to circumvent? Rhetorical question.

It's not allowed for the simple fact that `const` exists to prevent you from doing mistakes.

However, this is allowed:

```
const char *s = "hello";
char *t = (char*) s;
```

Would not recommend it though. It's still not allowed to modify a string literal through a non-const pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`const` in this context applies not the pointer, but to the value to which the pointer points.

`const char*` is a (non-const) pointer to a `const` `char`.

`char*` is a (non-const) pointer to a non-const `char`.

These are different types. The non-const version allows modification of the pointed-to value, and the const one doesn't.

C++ type safety rules ensure const-correctness. A non-const type can be implicitly cast to a const type, but not the other way around. Stripping away `const` requires an explicit cast (a [const cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), which is often a code smell and/or a bug).

If you meant to have a const pointer itself, you should use `char * const`. That's a `const` pointer to a non-const `char`. But note that a string literal like `"something"` is always `const`, it can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that **name = _name** was allowed.

Since they are both pointers, they will both be pointing to the same value.

That mean if we do **name[0] ='B'** that implies **_name[0] = 'B'** too (which is const) thats the reason why it's not allowed.

However, this is allowed

```
const char cc = 'a';
char c = 'b';

 c = cc;
```

**cc** and **c** are NOT pointers so changing **c** afterward will not change **cc**

Comment: I finally have an example that nobody can dispute. So casting a const object pointer to non const object pointer is UB in Cpp. But check the win32 structure REBARBANDINFO. It has a member, char *lpText; But if you are setting the text of the rebar you can pass it a const char* and cast it to char*. Or did the Win32 developers expect you allocate a char* ?